# How to redirect Tumblr posts after migrating to WordPress?

Tags: tumblr

I currently have a Tumblr site with hundreds of posts. None of them have actual titles and their resulting URLs look like this:

```
www.mywebsiteurl.com/post/120526237819
```

I'm not converting to WordPress but want all of these old URLs to properly redirect to my new WP Posts. At first, I tried the Tumblr Importer plugin but it created URLs like this:

```
www.mywebsiteurl.com/2017/05/13/
```

How can I get my old URLs to point to the new WP URL format?

Comment: if you are not in wordpress.com try this tutorial from wp begginer.http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-move-your-blog-from-tumblr-to-wordpress/

Comment: @RyanAW thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that doesn't work in my case. The WP Beginner shows an example URL as this: www.yourdomain.com/post/2610988231/my-post. In my example above, /my-post does not exist in my Tumblr URLs since those posts never had titles. This is the main issue.

Comment: I see tumblr has API key to fetch post data, You can check it here `https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2`  . On there can you fetch single post data that you can use to make a redirect pattern. ie: post title, post date check this screenshots https://prnt.sc/faz5yj